# How can I count the number of specific shapes with different color in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched on Google but I still cannot find a solution. I am looking for some VBA code to count on different shape with different color in excel.

Example: I have 5 rectangle shapes and 3 square shapes in sheet1.
2 rectangle shapes in yellow, 3 rectangle shapes in blue.
1 square shape in pink, 2 square shapes in yellow.
I need a VBA code to count the shapes in number with different color in cell A1 (Rectangle in yellow color), A2 (Rectangle in blue color), B1 (square in pink color), B2 (square in yellow color).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim shp As Shape
Dim shprange As ShapeRange
Dim CountyellowShape As Long
Dim CountpinkShape As Long
Dim CountblueShape As Long

For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes

    If shp.Type = msoGroup Then
        Set shprange = shp.Ungroup
        Set oMyGroup = shprange.Group

        If shprange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then CountChildShapeYELLOW = CountChildShapeYELLOW + 1
        If shprange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 153, 153) Then CountChildShapePINK = CountChildShapePINK + 1
        If shprange.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240) Then CountChildShapeBLUE = CountChildShapeBLUE + 1

    End If
Next shp

For Each shp In Sheet1.Shapes
    If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then CountShapeYELLOW = CountShapeYELLOW + 1
    If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 155, 153) Then CountShapePINK = CountShapePINK + 1
    If shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240) Then CountShapeBLUE = CountShapeBLUE + 1
Next shp

Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = CountShapeYELLOW + CountChildShapeYELLOW
Sheet1.Cells(2, 1) = CountShapePINK + CountChildShapePINK
Sheet1.Cells(3, 1) = CountShapeBLUE + CountChildShapeBLUE

End Sub
```

Thanking in advance.
Wiz Lee

Comment: What code have you tried?  You will need to determine what shapes().Fill.Backcolor will equal your "Pink", "Yellow", "Blue", etc....   Try to search Google for "vba for each shape in worksheet" to get a loop through your shapes.

Comment: It is an easy code, but have you started anything yourself?

Comment: I already add in my code as above post.

Comment: My code only can count the color in the shape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
Sub GetShapeProperties()
    Dim sShapes As Shape, lLoop As Long, lastRow As Long, i As Long, find As Boolean
    Dim wsStart As Worksheet

    Set wsStart = ActiveSheet

    'Loop through all shapes on active sheet
    For Each sShapes In wsStart.Shapes
        lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        'Increment Variable lLoop for row numbers
        lLoop = lLoop + 1
        i = 2
        With sShapes
            'Add shape properties
            find = False

            Do While find = False
                If (wsStart.Cells(i, 1).Value = MySplitFunction(.Name)(0)) Then
                    If (wsStart.Cells(i, 2).Value = .Fill.ForeColor.RGB) Then
                        find = True
                        lLoop = lLoop - 1
                    End If
                End If

                If i > lLoop Then
                    find = True
                End If

                i = i + 1
            Loop

            wsStart.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value = MySplitFunction(.Name)(0)
            wsStart.Cells(i - 1, 2).Value = .Fill.ForeColor.RGB
            wsStart.Cells(i - 1, 2).Interior.Color = .Fill.ForeColor.RGB
            wsStart.Cells(i - 1, 3).Value = wsStart.Cells(i - 1, 3).Value + 1
        End With
    Next sShapes
End Sub

Function MySplitFunction(s As String) As String()
    Dim temp As String

    Do
      temp = s
      s = Replace(s, "  ", " ") 'remove multiple white spaces
    Loop Until temp = s

    MySplitFunction = Split(Trim(s), " ") 'trim to remove starting/trailing space
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Zsmaster, I did tried your code in my excel workbook, but cannot automatic get the count number unless I press the run button and another problem is if I did not blank the count cell and straight away press the run button, the count number will not tally.

Comment: Try to attach the function to an event, so you don't need to push a button. You need blank the count cell before run the function.

Comment: Is that any code can auto count without blank the cell?

Comment: Try to add this to the beginning of the code: Range("C:C").Clear

Comment: Its work, but when refresh on second time the count number will change, and come to 3rd time only back to the right figure.